# How to read a method body with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo, methodbase

Is it possible to find out anything about a Method body with reflection?

How?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`MethodInfo.GetMethodBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx).

That provides you access to anything you want... if you're happy to work through the IL etc yourself.

It's possible that the [Mono Cecil library](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) will provide more help - I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Thanks again dude.  You're always hooking me up.

Answer (score 0):

Talking of Mono.Cecil, it will give you access to the method body in a way that will look very familiar if you have ever peeked into a .NET assembly with ILDASM.