# How to convert MSIL code into C#?

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I want to print method body on my web page using reflection. See attached image file, in that there is a GetAge method. When I select this method from the dropdown than body part of this method should be displayed on screen. The method is in DLL file.
How can I achieve this in VB.NEt

EDIT:
Some how I have succeeded to get MSIL code from DLL. Now I want to convert that code to C# code using code behind. Is there any way to do this?

[image: Method body]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2693922/284240 (so no, there's no `methodBody.ToString()`). But maybe this helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14058/Parsing-the-IL-of-a-Method-Body

Comment: And another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986563/how-to-read-a-method-body-with-reflection

Comment: The method is in DLL file.